# Calculating angle made with center of room - am I doing this correctly ? What method can I use?

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, angle

[The room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEl3I.jpg)

Note: it is say supposed to say 4,0 for the first location. 4,4 refers to the center of the room.
Basically I have cameras placed in those three locations - (4,0), (0,8), and (8,8). I want to calculate the angle this makes with the center of the room. I have come up with the following so far: (4,0) makes angle 90, (0,8) makes angle 45, and (8,8)  also makes angle 45. Is this correct? If I were to say, have a camera at (5,1), how would I calculate the angle ? My objective is to create a map of the room, am I doing this in the right way?
Thank you!

Comment: Which angle are you referring to? If the 3 positions are fixed, you can try extending lines to the axis to form right triangles. From there, the sine and cosine of the angle can be easily obtained.

Comment: Why is your coordinate system left handed?

Comment: @David I am referring to the angle the camera makes with the center of the room.

Comment: I am still unsure what you mean by that. The 3 angles you give do not appear to be with respect to the center of the room, but rather the angle of the line joining the camera to the center of the room with respect to a vertical line.

Comment: @David in the view of the camera, when it is looking at the center of the room. I hope that clarifies my question. In this situtation are my estimations right ?

Comment: $(8,8)$makes $ 135^{\circ}$ Right?

Answer (score 1):

I assume corner (8,8) makes $ 135 ^{\circ}$ to horizontal in your scheme.And that for the coordinate axes reference you mentioned in your sketch as parallel to x-axis angle =0

For any other point in the room to calculate required anti-clockwise rotation use the formula

$$ \tan ^{-1} \dfrac{y-4}{x-4}$$

where arctan2 inverse function should be used always with proper sign.